# Select column ignore beginning numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column that I need to select but it has an inconsistent amount of numbers/formatting in the beginning

The column values are ideally supposed to be structured like:

```
# Question_-_Answer
```

But here are some examples which make it hard to remove the numbers in the beginning

```
0 Question1_-_50-60
1.Question_-_apple
12Question_-_40/50
13 Question_-_orange
14.Question_-_apple
15.  Question_-_orange2
```

Is there a way I can query this column so that it ignores everything *until* the first alphabetical character while also not removing any characters/alphanumerical values in the question and answer portion?

Comment: I really suggest fixing your design, the question number should be in a different column entirely it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PATINDEX` and `STUFF` to achieve this:

```
SELECT STUFF(V.YourString,1,PATINDEX('%[A-z]%',V.YourString)-1,'')
FROM (VALUES('0 Question1_-_50-60'),
            ('1.Question_-_apple'),
            ('12Question_-_40/50'),
            ('13 Question_-_orange'),
            ('14.Question_-_apple'),
            ('15.  Question_-_orange2'))V(YourString);
```

This removes all characters up to the first alpha character.

Comment: If you can explain why this doesn't answer the question, @Sebazz44 , and you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72203730/edit) your question, then i might be able to address it.